# Excel Formula that generates a #REF! error

Tags: excel, vba

In Microsoft Excel I have a cell that generates a #REF! error (because it refers to a worksheet that's been deleted).  I want to write VBA code that will retrieve the formula that was in that cell.  Has the REF error wiped out the original formula so it's lost forever?  I know that IsError(ActiveCell.Value) will tell me whether a cell has an error, and I know that ActiveCell.Value will give me the error number (2023 for #REF), but that still leaves me without the original formula.  If I had the actual formula, I could change the sheet name and put it back in the troublesome cell.

Comment: The #REF! part should only have wiped out the sheet name. If you want to use a different sheet name, just replace #REF! with whatever that sheet name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check = Range("A1").Formula 'Reference to the cell your formula is in
```

Comment: I believe that there will be `#REF!` where the sheet name had been previously, correct? However, the rest of the formula should be intact.

Comment: Exactly, but he is asking for the actual formula in his last sentence.

Comment: YES !   cells(1,1).Value  gives me only the error, but cells(1,1).Formula gives me exactly what I was looking for, viz., the original formula with just the worksheet name lost.   THANK YOU JvdV

Answer (score 3):

*Has the #REF! error wiped out the original formula so it's lost forever?*

**Yes!** You cannot reverse it.

---

However, if you are looking for an easy way, to keep the formulas, before deleting workbook that they refer to, you may add a `'` sign in front of each formula. Thus, the formulas would be saved as text and you would avoid #REF!:

```
Public Sub AllFormulasToText()

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If myCell.HasFormula Then myCell.Value = "'" & myCell.Formula
    Next myCell

End Sub
```